# Color legend in a demography plot

Tags: r, plot, legend, forecasting

I have some demogdata from the package `demography` and I want to put a color legend in the plot. Can someone help me?

For example, in this picture I want to put a lateral color legend with the years from 1940 to 2009.

```
plot.demogdata(portugal,series='male',years=1940:2009)
```

[image]

Comment: Since the question is about software manipulation rather than a statistical question, it may likely be closed or migrated. When it's migrated, I'd suggest you at least add "R" to your tag, and provide a minimal working example (e.g. what you have now, and what you'd like to add.) Otherwise the response rate would be very low.

Comment: Still no code example.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is (demonstrated with a reproducible example):

```
library(demography)

fr.mort_age = extract.ages(fr.mort,0:60,F)    
fr.mort_age_yr = extract.years(fr.mort_age,1918:1950)    
plot.demogdata(fr.mort_age_yr,series='male')   
legend("bottomright",legend=unique(fr.mort_age_yr$year),
  col=rainbow(length(fr.mort_age_yr$year)*1.25), ncol=5, pch=19, 
  title="Year", cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Close. But the rainbow palette used in demography (and the associated rainbow package) extends the range by 25% to avoid the reds at either end being confused. I've updated your answer to fix this.

Comment: How can I do if I want a legend like this:
https://www.google.pt/search?q=scale+colour+legend&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=QG6xUp7jEKaM7Qb8koAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=922#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=Qtl6QYjI0ORhtM%3A%3BzMRqP-oTaDUl3M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mathworks.com%252Fhelp%252Freleases%252FR2013b%252Fmatlab%252Fref%252Fcolorbar1.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mathworks.com%252Fhelp%252Fmatlab%252Fref%252Fcolorbar.html%3B768%3B576

Comment: @user2898085. Please ask this as a new question.